# How can explode some text that's in brackets?

Tags: php

I need to explode some content like this :

For example this is my content :

[A]            [C#m]           [Dm]          [Dm]

how can I explode the charecters between [ ] and put them in a array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to achieve that:

```php
$content = '[A] [C#m] [Dm] [Dm]';
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $content, $matches);

$result = $matches[1];
```

The result will be an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

For the example where they are adjacent `][`, you could explode after trimming `[` and `]`.  Your example has a space in between `]` and `[`:

```
$result = explode('] [', trim($string, '[]'));
```